# Настройка формата новостей в шаблоне Joomla

Tags: шаблоны, joomla

Не могу разобраться с шаблоном Joomla.

На странице категорий ([к примеру](urist.lg.ua/novini.html)) новости отображаются нормально. А на главной странице я хочу сделать так же, как и [тут](urist.lg.ua/novini.html), то есть черточку между новостями и убрать пункты типа "последнее обновление 09.08.2012"...

Где именно надо копать, а то уже все перерыл! (((

Comment: Ссылки не рабочие

Comment: И версию joomla скажите